# Bitmap.Save "Object is currently in use elsewhere" Threading Issue

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, gdi, system.drawing

I have some code like this:

```
    public void SaveImage(int Counter)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var image = FinalImage;
            if (image != null)
            {
                image.Save(FinalImageSaveLocation + "test" + Counter + ".bmp");
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
    }
```

I have a for loop creating x amount of images using similar code below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  Pencil.DrawImage(image, x, y); //Pencil is created at a initialisation stage
  SaveImage(i);                  //by Pencil = Graphics.FromImage(FinalImage);
}
```

I thought by putting the SaveImage method as a task this would speed things up but I assume I'm getting the exception is because the next iteration of the loop is trying to draw to the final image object whilst the Save is occurring. I guess I could use a lock but I fear that would slow things down?

Is there a fix or should I just remove the task?

Comment: The Bitmap class is not thread-safe so you cannot access this from several threads at the same time. If this means you have to lock, to prevent it, or make a copy that you can save in your own time, you'll just have to pick a solution and go with it, but you absolutely cannot access it from multiple threads. You're also mentioning that you're drawing on it while you're saving. Are you saving rendered images? If so you should probably end up with a lock or a queue, or you might end up spinning up tasks faster than they can complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you can't access an image from multiple threads simultaniously. You have to do some synchronization. if performance is a problem, you can perform the following trick:

In your save method, get a lock on the image. Save to a memory stream, release the lock and finally save to the disk. (since disk IO is very slow).

The lock part is only usefull when needing actual synchronization. Since a Bitmap is not thread safe, you should not access it using multiple threads in the first place and hence, therefore synchronization shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing into a bitmap and saving it in another thread is perfectly fine, as long as you don't do it at the same time.  GDI+ contains a check to verify that you don't access the bitmap from more than one thread at the same time, that's why you get the exception.

A simple workaround is to create a *new* bitmap before you start drawing.  Dispose it in the task after you saved it.  You have to code this carefully though, you'll still have a problem if saving the bitmap takes longer than the drawing.  You'll run out of memory.  A semaphore can solve that, initialize it to the number of bitmaps you're comfortable with.  Depends on the size of the bitmap.  Then call WaitOne() in the drawing method, Release() in the saving method.